# Configure android ndk for android studio code suggestion

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I'm new to android NDK and just know how to use native code in an java project as in this tutorial: http://kn-gloryo.github.io/Build_NDK_AndroidStudio_detail/

But when writing in C++ the IDE features for code completion, suggestion and other stuff disappear, while in java those features work as usual.

I tried to import some ndk sample from google, they are all written in C++ instead of calling native code from JNI as I'm doing, and the projects support code completion.

Can anyone show me a way to configure Android Studio for code completion to work when developing with NDK and JNI?

Comment: You could try the Hello JNI sample. You can import it when you start android studio -> import android code sample. In this sample the stuff you want should work.

Comment: The hello-jni and other NDK example from google works fine 'cause they are using the experimental gradle. Is there a way to use the traditional gradle to work with NDK because I don't want to use experimental plugin.